# ggplot2 graph boxes based on range of values (min max)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use ggplot2 to create a simple bar/box plot showing the range (min-max) of values by 3 treatments. I have a simple 3x3 dataframe showing treatment, min, and max values, as follows:

```
Treatment A: (68-88)
Treatment B: (95-105)
Treatment C: (110-140)
```

All I would like to do is show the Treatment along the X axis and boxes of various sizes representing the min-max range along the Y axis. In my dataset, Treatment A would be lowest but would have a slightly wider box than Treatment B (intermediate). The box for Treatment B would be the narrowest.  Treatment C would have the widest box and would also have the highest values.

Can this be done using ggplot2? It seems pretty simple.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `my_data <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                      Treatment = c("A", "B", "C"),
                      min = c(68,95,110),
                      max = c(88,105,140));
library(ggplot2);
ggplot(my_data, aes(Treatment, (min+max)/2, height = max - min)) +
  geom_tile()`

Comment: Excellent - thanks!  I can customize this code, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Answer in comments:

```
my_data <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                      Treatment = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                      min = c(68,95,110), 
                      max = c(88,105,140))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(my_data, aes(Treatment, (min+max)/2, height = max - min)) + 
  geom_tile()
```